# Alternate code in objective of java

Tags: objective-c

recently i have switched from Android to iPhone.....could any one let me know what is the alternete code in Objective c...Thankx in Advance

```
etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);

name = etName.getText().toString();
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you need to use an IBOutlet to connect the text field to one of the instance variables in your application delegate, and then call the `stringValue` method on that field.

Comment: could you provide me appropriate code in Objective c..Thank You

Comment: Since it's an UITextField, you want to use the `text` method instead of the `stringValue` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@talktobijju As David says, you create a text field like so in your controller.

```
// code in the interface
IBOutlet UITextField *etName;
```

Then you connect the text field UI GUI element in Interface Builder to etName in your controller. Afterwards, you can access the data that's typed into the text field like so.

```
// code in the implementation
NSString *textFieldString = [etName text];
```

I would look at some iPhone tutorials that provide more detail in how to setup and use UITextField.